# Javascript: Cannot set property 'readOnly' of null

Tags: javascript

Link to the javascript file is placed at the bottom of the html file, right after `</body>` tag. A function resv is called with parameters that are id of input elements.
Here is the javascript function:

```
function resv(cmt,rst){
    var commt = document.getElementById(cmt).value;
    var reslt = document.getElementById(rst).value;
    ..
    ..
    ..
    document.getElementById(rst).value = "Some text";
    ..
    ..
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            if (ajaxRequest.responseText === "OK") {
              document.getElementById(rst).readOnly = true;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Using `alert(commt);` and `alert(reslt);` I have checked that the value is being correctly passed. A few lines later, which includes an ajax call, when the same element is referenced by its id to reset its readOnly attribute, it returns null. Any idea why this is happening, especially after an ajax call? Some others using Chrome browsers have reported similar issues.

Comment: can you check `rst` parameter may be changed after an ajax call ?

Comment: please check if you ajax response is not changing html or value of rst

Comment: Alerting `commt` or `reslt` seems to be totally irrelevant to your code?

Comment: Raunak, the value of rst gets changed during the script, but as long as the id is same, why should it matter?

Comment: Teemu, alerting is not part of the code. It was just to check that the references are being correctly passed.

Comment: "*…right after </body>*" it should be right **before** the closing body tag (though browsers will put it in the right place for you).

Comment: There isn't any dependency on the ajax call is there? Because it's not synchronous.

Comment: RobG, the script was initially placed just before </body> tag. Someone suggested to place it beyond that. Either way, the problem persists.

Comment: The AJAX call likely has not returned when you call *document.getElementById(rst)* the second time, so if you remove the element from the document and are expecting AJAX to restore it, that may not have happened yet. Whoever suggested putting script outside the body was wrong, script elements must be inside the body or head elements (though browsers will auto-correct such errors).

Comment: RobG, the element referenced by rst is not being removed anywhere.

Comment: Since rst is a local variable within the scope of the function it can only be referenced inside of that function.
When you set a callback for onreadystatechange, that block of code gets executed sometime after resv() has finished and had its local variables cleaned. so when document.getElementById(rst) is called, rst is undefined at that time.

Comment: Dylan, what is the solution then? Setting the ajax to load synchronously too doesn't work.

Comment: @DylanJamesMcGannon No, local variables are not "cleaned", whatever that means. They are most definitely available to nested functions which close over them.

Comment: Place a breakpoint on the line in question. There, examine the value or `rst`, and the value of `document.getElementById(rst)`.

Comment: torazaburo, there is no value for rst and Cannot read property 'value' of null

Comment: @torazabura by cleaned I meant that the variable leaves scope and gets deleted. Sorry if that isn't the case, it's how i thought it worked.

Comment: torazabura, your suggestion actually helped to troubleshoot as was suggested initially by Toon. I also had a variable named rst with some value in it. Renaming it solved the issue.